# Gridview with imageview and textview

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I found this example http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/ but I get Force Close and I don't understand why...
In LogCat I get :

```
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Linearlayout in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44dac780
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-22 09:40:00.767: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(320):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
```

Have anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example i think all the xml tags like LinearLayout, ImageView etc are lower case. That is causing the problm